# What do these Jquery selectors mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't make out what these 2 lines mean:

```
var template = $("#" + model + " #grid #template").clone();
var templateHtml = $("#templatebody", template).html();
```

I can't understand the selectors here.I know what clone() and html() do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#" + model + " #grid #template")
```

This is looking for an element with the `id` of `template` inside an element id `grid`, inside and element with the `id` which is set in the `model` variable.

For example, if `model` was the string: 'container':

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="grid">
        <div id="template"></div> <!-- this div would be selected -->
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$("#templatebody", template)
```

This is a 'context' selector; it is looking for the `#templatebody` element inside the element which is contained in the `template` variable. Note that a context selector is irrelevant in this case as there should only ever be one element in a given page with a set `id`.

Example

```
var template = $("#container"); // note - can also be a string: "#container"
$("#templatebody", template)
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="templatebody"></div> <!-- this div would be selected -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one is fine the element with the ID `template`, inside another element with the ID `grid` which is inside a parent element with the ID of the `model` variable.

Set model to `test`

```
model = "test"
```

Results in this:

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="grid">
         <div id="template">   <--- this element is found
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This implies that there is more than one element with the same ID in your HTML, which is not a good idea as it will often confuse selectors. (I'm fairly certain it's invalid HTML as well)

The second is simply find the element with ID `templateBody` inside the template element found in the first selector.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose `model` contains the string `"model"`. The following selector:

```
$("#" + model + " #grid #template")
```

finds the element with id = `template` and contained inside an element with id = `grid` which itself is contained within an element with id = `model`. The selector:

```
$("#templatebody", template)
```

finds the element with id = `templatebody` inside the (clone of) previously matched element.

Having said that, the first selector can be written as `$("#template")` since ids should be unique. If this is not the case then you will get unexpected results. Also, cloning elements in a way that introduces duplicate IDs is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

first of, 3 ID in an selector? feels a bit overkill. But what you do is that you clone the `#template` and from the clone you find a child with an id of `#templatebody` and take out its HTML content. you dont need to clone it to fetch the HTML text.

```
// Find the #template that is a child of #grid and #grid is a child of #<insertModel> and clone it
var template = $("#" + model + " #grid #template").clone();
// Find #templatebody child of template ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 ) and get the HTML text thats in #templatebody
```

var templateHtml = $("#templatebody", template).html();

if you have a markup looking like:

```
<div id="model">
    <div id="grid">
        <div id="template"><b>Hi</b> there!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

your templateHTML variable will contain `'<b>Hi</b> there!'`

Answer (score 1):

```
var template = $("#" + model + " #grid #template")
```

Would select the id with grid and template and the id of your model variable.  To find out what this is you can alert(model) which will display the value.

You then select the templatebody element which is contained in the template variable you defined previously.

Answer (score 1):

the code is equivalent, in the sense of finding the same element, to writing

```
var template = $("#" + model).find("#grid).find("#template").clone(),
    templateHtml = template.find("#templatebody").html();
```

- find what everelement has and id that equals the value of model,
- within that find an element with id grid
- within that find one with id of template.
- Clone the found element search
- within the clone for one with the id templateBody.

however if the html is valid then there's only going to be one with the id #template in which case the code could be simplified to

```
var template = $("#template").clone();
    template.find("#templateBody");
```

Except that that does not test the parent/child relation between template and grid and grid and model. If that's needed the simplified version can't be used

Answer (score 0):

the first line finds an element with ID #template within a #grid which is within #" + model.

IDs are supposed to be unique on the page, and the first line ideally should be replaced with:

```
var template = $("#template").clone();
template.attr("id", "newid"); // assign a new unique id
```